# How to get a web application form to auto-submit upon the entry of barcode data in an INPUT Text field or Textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, barcode

Please help me out on this, I have a search input text field that, that I want use bar-code scanner to fill in the value, and major challenge here is how to get the form auto-submit upon entry of the barcode data.
Below is a sample of the code that I have tried but didn't work.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="search" role="form" action="process.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="dl_search" id="dl_search"></form>

<script>
$("#dl_search").bind('input propertychange', function(){
    // this.form.submit();
    // $("form").submit();
    // $("#search").submit();
});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your bar-code scanner simulates changing the data in the `input` field, use [jQuery change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) ...

```
$('#dl_search').change(function() {
    $('#search').submit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks BareNakedCoder for your response, I have tried it, & it didn't work.

Comment: I guess my assumption was wrong.  Which bar code scanner are you using (vendor name & model)?  Did it come with any software such as a Javascript lib?

Answer (score 0):

You can sometimes program the scanner itself to perform an action after every scan.  For instance you could have it "press enter" after every scan.  I use a Symbol LS4000i (fairly cheap and entry level) and it can do this.

Comment: Thanks Heirophant, please do one get to program the scanner the "Press enter action" am using same scanner that you mentioned.

Comment: The way you do this is by scanning control barcodes which are located in the owners manual.  the ls4000i manual can be found here: http://cleversoftsolutions.com/descargas/utilidades/Lectores/Symbol/LS400Xi%20PRG.pdf